# angular get child attributes not only the id

Tags: angular

I have an object Modulator define in modulator.ts

```
import { Tone } from './tone';

export class Modulator {
  id: number;
  x: number;
  octave: number;
  tone: Tone;
}
```

my Tone object is defined in tone.ts

```
 export class Tone {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  color: string;
  digit: integer;
  userColor: string;
  userName: string;
}
```

When I try to display a Modulator in a view, I manage to get all Modulator attributes but I can't display the related Tone attributes.

`{{modulator.tone}}` returns the id of the tone but `{{modulator.tone.(some tone attribute)}}` returns nothing.

How can I access to my tone object via his parent Modulator?

Edit:
Thanks to yours comments I understand my mistake. I'm loading my data from a service with a get query which only return the id of the Tone object. All my Tones are already loaded in my app by another service.

My question is now how can I replace my resonator.tone which is just the id by the Tone object?

Comment: `{modulator.tone.(some tone attribute)` should work but if you have not intialized `tone` then it will not work ...please provide more code where you initialize `modulator`

Comment: Can you code the same on stackblitz

Comment: @lil-works, it's look like you're equaling modulador.tone=id, not modulador.tone=someTone

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct except for a minor change as below:

```
import { Tone } from './tone';

export class Modulator {
  id: number;
  x: number;
  octave: number;
  tone: Tone = new Tone();  // <=== HERE
}
```

Or else 'tone' will be `undefined`